# create multi-dimensional array with named dimensions and elements compactly

Tags: r

A while ago I wanted a simpler way of creating multidimensional arrays with named dimensions.

I ended up writing a function that has worked really well for me but I worry it may be somewhat of a hack and that there may be a better way of doing. So before passing this on to a colleague I'm seeking advice here.

What I want to do is to be able to create multi-dimensional arrays where the name of a dimension is specified by the name of a vector and the names of the elements are specified by the contents of that vector. e.g.

```
  sex <- c("F","M")
  name2 <- c("a","b","c")
```

This can be written out like so.

```
  dimnames1 <- list( sex=sex, name2=name2 )
  dim1 <- sapply(dimnames1, function(x) length(x))
  a <- array(0,dim=dim1, dimnames=dimnames1)
  a

   name2
sex a b c
  F 0 0 0
  M 0 0 0
```

But I wanted to be able to keep this more compact :

I wrote this function that enables that.

```
  array_named <- function( ...)
    {

    listArgs <- as.list(match.call()[-1])

    #works only if args are specified by actual ranges not by a varname
    #dimnames1 <- lapply(listArgs,eval)

    #works, I'm not sure why n=3
    dimnames1 <- lapply(listArgs,function(x){eval.parent(x, n=3)})

    #setting dimensions of array from dimnames1
    dim1 <- sapply(dimnames1, function(x) length(x))

    #creating array and filling with fill value
    a <- array(0, dim=dim1, dimnames=dimnames1)

    return(a)
  }
```

This allows passing vectors by name :

```
array_named( sex=sex, name2=name2 )

name2
sex a b c
  F 0 0 0
  M 0 0 0
```

and directly e.g.

```
array_named( a=c(1,2), b=c('x','y') )

   b
a   x y
  1 0 0
  2 0 0
```

Are there problems with this is there a more sensible way of doing ?

Comment: `array` can handle named dimensions; unless I'm missing something, you could define your function as a simple wrapper `ff = function(...) array(0, dim = lengths(list(...)), dimnames = list(...))` -- `ff(sex = sex, name2 = name2); ff(a = c(1, 2), b = c("x", "y"), c = c("A", "B"))`

Comment: Thanks Alexis, this is perfect and does exactly what I want. I should have thought of that. If you want to put in as an answer I will accept.